# Docker with php, file upload failed, $_FILE is empty

Tags: php, docker

Strange is, upload failed just at local env, it work on production and dev env. All of these use docker to run the project, and l checked my local php.ini in docker. it was set correctly, here is some info about my file upload

post data:

```
------------KM7GI3GI3Ef1ei4ae0gL6GI3GI3Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filename"

test.pdf
------------KM7GI3GI3Ef1ei4ae0gL6GI3GI3Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="PHPSESSID"

<?php echo session_id(); ?>
------------KM7GI3GI3Ef1ei4ae0gL6GI3GI3Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileNameFormat"

{time}{rand:6}
------------KM7GI3GI3Ef1ei4ae0gL6GI3GI3Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile"; filename="test.pdf"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream


------------KM7GI3GI3Ef1ei4ae0gL6GI3GI3Ij5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Upload"

Submit Query
------------KM7GI3GI3Ef1ei4ae0gL6GI3GI3Ij5--
```

php section:

```
<?php var_dump($_FILE);?>
```

result:

```
NULL
```

part setting of my php.ini

```
post_max_size = 2000M

max_input_time = 6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

memory_limit = 1280M

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; File Uploads ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
; http://php.net/file-uploads
file_uploads = On

; Temporary directory for HTTP uploaded files (will use system default if not
; specified).
; http://php.net/upload-tmp-dir
;upload_tmp_dir =

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
upload_max_filesize = 2000M

; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 2000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Is the request content-type set to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Oh, it's [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.files.php), not `$_FILE`

Comment: @Phil sorry my fault, l will edit it. And l need to check the content-type, it is a flash file upload pulgin

Comment: @Phil l found the case of problem, because of setting of `max_input_time` and `upload_max_filesize `, this two setting is too large

Answer (score 1):

set the `max_input_time` and `upload_max_filesize` to a common value, like 3000. these two setting's value is too large case php can't admit it. l reset these setting into 3000, and restart the container, done it. Now file upload can work successfully.